# Determining CRS from ASCII file?

Tags: coordinate-system, ascii

It is possible to know the CRS from an ascii file?

The information I have about it in the heading of the ascii file is the x and y corners:

xllcorner     -10,000416206603
yllcorner     34,999583430181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are probably geographic coordinates, probably WGS84.
Try it with http://projfinder.com/

Comment: geographic coordinates with a comma?

Comment: @artwork21 Many countries use a comma as a decimal separator instead of a period, including Tunisia (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)), which is [where those coordinates could be](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B059'58.5%22N+10%C2%B000'01.5%22E/@35.1281144,9.7101288,8.17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.9995834!4d10.0004162) if one assumes they are both positive (east and north).

Comment: As a German I did not even notice that ;)